# how to create variables+table (ID & DATE) - SQL

Tags: sql, date, hiveql

I am new to SQL/HiveQL.

How can I create a table with 2 variables: ORG_ID (string) and TIME_PERIOD (date) like this:

```
ORG_ID | TIME_PERIOD
C2222  | 2018-01-31
C2222  | 2018-02-28
C2222  | 2018-03-31
...
C2222  | 2021-05-31
C2222  | 2021-06-30
D3333  | 2018-01-31
D3333  | 2018-02-28
D3333  | 2018-03-31
...
D3333  | 2021-05-31
D3333  | 2021-06-30
W2345  | 2018-01-31
W2345  | 2018-02-28
W2345  | 2018-03-31
...
W2345  | 2021-05-31
W2345  | 2021-06-30
```

My 6 IDs: C2222, D3333, W2345, E2111, T7232, U8967

TIME_PERIOD contains the last day of each month between 2018-01-31 and 2021-06-30 (inclusive).

I don't have these variables created in the database, how to create them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [table_name] (     
    ORG_ID varchar(24) NOT NULL,     
    TIME_PERIOD Date NOT NULL    
)
```

It is also good practice to have a column in your table with a primary key for indexing, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE [table_name] (
    [RowID] Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    ORG_ID varchar(24) NOT NULL,     
    TIME_PERIOD Date NOT NULL    
)
```

`RowID` will auto incurment (count) and is the primary index on the table.

Comment: Thanks James. How can I create the variables ORG_ID and TIME_PERIOD first? I don't know

Comment: the create table statement above will also create the column names you are looking for.  You need to run/execute the statement against the database and a new table will be created with the column names "RowID", ORG_ID", & "TIME_PERIOD"

Comment: Thanks James. But those variables/columns, at least ORG_ID & TIME_PERIOD will be empty. I don't have them in the database, I need to create them as per the above. ORG_ID with those 6 IDs, and TIME_PERIOD with last day of the month from Jan 2018 up to Jun 2021. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Now that you table exists, simply insert the data.  

    `INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] ([ORG_ID] ,[TIME_PERIOD])  
    VALUES  
    ('C2222', '20180131'),  
    ('C2222', '2018-02-28'),  
    ...  
    Go`

[T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks very much James. My problem is that I have 300 IDs in reality, so 300x30 (months) this means 9000 entries I would have to do if I follow your code. Could you think of other, quicker way?

Comment: Look into 'BULK INSERT' from files. Here is the documentation if you are using [MS SQL SERVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)